# How to enable library in ffmpeg without build ffmpeg from source (linux)?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, make, xubuntu, build

I have the xubuntu 18.04. I installed ffmpeg from ubuntu repository and built libaom. So, how to enable libaom in ffmpeg without reinstall ffmpeg from source ([ffmpeg compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#FFmpeg) or [ffmpeg compilation guide screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U15eW.png))?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to compile FFmpeg yourself or find a precompiled binary configured with `--enable-libaom`.

It isn't possible to enable an additional additional library to an already-compiled binary that is not configured to use it.

The linux builds on https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg are very good ones that are always kept up to date, and already come with `libaom` enabled, so you don't have to do it yourself.